# Render Dynamic Variables in JSON Feed with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json, api

I'm just looking at creating an API for our customers to interact with our main Rails 3 application.

For one part, I wanted the json response to contain some a form. Basically some form code that we control and appears on their site.

I have this working ok (simplified):

```
def login_form
  @response = Form.find_by_something(params[:something_else])
  if @response 
    render :status=>200, :json=>{:response => @response} 
  end
end
```

And on the client side, I can fetch:

```
@logins = HTTParty.get("#{set_auth_url}/api/v1/logins.json?auth_token=xyz&something_else=abc").parsed_response
```

And display the form

```
= @logins["response"].html_safe
```

The problem is, the form code has some dynamic variables:

For example:

```
<div class="login">
  <FORM name="form1" METHOD="get" action="<%= request.path %>?">
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="chal" VALUE="<%= params['challenge'] %>">
  <% if @current_location['success_url'] %>
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="userurl" VALUE="/success">
  <% end %>
  <input type="hidden" name="UserName" placeholder="Username" value="<%= @user['username']['username'] %>">
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="btn">
</div>
```

I'm wondering if this is a good idea? And if so, how can I break those variables out in the html??

If it's not, could someone recommend a nicer way to go about it.

Comment: So you are storing html templates in the database and return them for the client to render in their web page? Just to be sure.

Comment: Hey. In part - just the form code.

Comment: @simonmorley Does the form data remain constant not taking the actual content Have a better solution to this using javascript template

Comment: Looks like the form should be a view. Is there any reason the form html is being stored in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Javascript Template for this as in Jquery Template or Mustache or Handlebar

so keep the form in the on the client side like this

I will describe it using Mustache over here
    
    ....

```
...

    <script id="template" type="text/template">
      <div class="login">
      <FORM name="form1" METHOD="get" action={{request_path}}>
      <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="chal" VALUE={{challenges}}>
      {{boolean_value}} 
      <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="userurl" VALUE="/success">
      {{/boolean_value}}
      <input type="hidden" name="UserName" placeholder="Username" value={{user_name}}>
      <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="btn">
     </div>
    </script>

</html>
```

Next part is getting the response in form of ajax

The using any Javascript Framework I guess it can be achieved I'm using jQuery over here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      // make ajax call over here
      success: function(data)  {
        // JSON DATA 
         var template = $('script#template').html();
         $([container where html is place]).html(Mustache.to_html(template,data));
      }

    })
 })
```

Hope this Help

Not sure how would you want though of plain Form html tag intead of form_tag since it does not contain an authenticity token

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've not used either of these before. I'm confused how this is requested though? I need their get request to pull the form down in it's entirety.

Comment: Took me some time to get round to this and I'm sorry that I couldn't award you the bounty. Not sure this is quite right yet but it's almost there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Are those variables known on server-side when preparing the response? In that case, I'd try around with running them through templating engine `:json=> { :response => ERB.new(@response).result(binding) }` - client would receive only the html applicable in his case.

Comment: Hey. Thanks. Does that mean I leave the standard vars in the text_input? And Rails does the rest?

Comment: That works however, some of the code pulls params from the url. <%= params['challenge'] %> This isn't rendered. What's the way to get these params?